# How to check audio while rotation of screen in Android?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm implementing media player in Android. I'm facing some problem while I run my app.

My media player is reinitialize when I rotate or orient of landscape / portrait my screen and song is played doubly back by back. How to solve this? I want song is playing only once when I rotate my screen.

Comment: Please read about the Activity life cycle then think about your question again.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this through Activity life cycle.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        if(mPlayer != null) {
            if(!mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        }
   }

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.pause();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.reset();
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```